# Problem with SVG: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/logo.svg' in '/Users/ricaldito/Desktop/gpt3_jsm/src/components/navbar'

Tags: reactjs, svg

```
import React from 'react';
import { RiMenu3Line, RiCloseline } from 'react-icons/ri';
import logo from '../../assets/logo.svg';
import './navbar.css';

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="gpt3__navbar">
      <div className="gpt3__navbar-links">
        <div className="gpt3__navbar-links_logo">
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

I tried to modify the '../../assets/logo.svg'; but it doesnt change at all.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `logo.svg` file in your `public` folder, then add it as a `src` attribute in your `<img />` tag, like so:

```
<img src={`/asset/logo.svg`} alt=""/>
```

You do not need to import `logo.svg` in your React code, so you can remove the following line:

```
import logo from '../../assets/logo.svg';
```